# Node.Js app cannot be deployed to Heroku successfully

Tags: node.js, heroku, deployment, web-deployment

There's this [tutorial](https://medium.com/dailyjs/real-time-apps-with-typescript-integrating-web-sockets-node-angular-e2b57cbd1ec1) which has a working chat app. You can find the chat app on [GitHub](https://github.com/luixaviles/socket-io-typescript-chat).

I'm trying to deploy the git code to Heroku without success.
The GitHub is separated to client/server architecture so it requires to start node server and `ng serve` to client. Do I need 2 dynos for it? Do I need to edit the Procfile? The server is using process.env.PORT but the client one is hardcoded.

I'm very new to Heroku and Node.js so any help is meaningful to me.

Answer (score 0):

The GitHub project that you ask about is pretty complex and it doesn't seem to have ane Heroku deployment instructions, without knowing the project it's hard to give you any concrete solution, but I'll try to answer in general how such applications are usually deployed and hopefully it will help you solve your problems.

For applications like this it is common to split the backend and the frontend part and have it deployed and hosted separately, either as two separate dynos if you want to host both on Heroku, or e.g. hosting the backend part on Heroku and the frontend part on Netlify or a similar service.

Another option could be to make the backend serve the frontend e.g. on the `/` path while having all of the backend endpoints available as `/api/*` or something similar (or on a different port but this is not possible on Heroku). Having it on the same host and port but with a prefix for the api has the advantage of simplifying the CORS related matters, as the origin is the same so no cross-origin issues arise.

If you're using WebSockets then it is slightly more complicated - make sure to read:

- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/websockets

but either way you can still move your frontend to Netlify or something similar and keep the backend on Heroku if you want.

It's hard to give you any more specific answer to this question. I see that you are new here, so next time try to write a more specific question and narrow down the problem so that you can show a small code example that people could actually read and help you.